# Intuit Partner Platform Make Check Error

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I receive this error when I make a check:

You must select a product/service or an account for each split line with either an amount or a billable $$customer$$.

Here is my code:

```
 public void BuildCheckAddRq(Order order)
    {
        if (_qboSettings.MerchantPercent > 0 || _qboSettings.MerchantFee > 0)
        {
            Check newCheck = new Check(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value

            var total = (order.OrderTotal * _qboSettings.MerchantPercent) + _qboSettings.MerchantFee;

            newCheck.Header = new CheckHeader();
            newCheck.Header.TotalAmt = total;
            newCheck.Header.TotalAmtSpecified = true;
            newCheck.Header.TxnDate = System.DateTime.Now;
            newCheck.Header.Note = "Merchant Account Fees";
            newCheck.Header.BankAccountName = _qboSettings.DefaultAccount;
            newCheck.Header.DocNumber = order.Id.ToString();


            newCheck.Header.BankAccountId = new IdType { idDomain = idDomainEnum.QBO, Value = GetAccountId(_qboSettings.DefaultAccount) };
            newCheck.Header.EntityName = _qboSettings.MerchantVendorAcct;
            newCheck.Header.EntityType = EntityTypeEnum.Vendor;
            //newCheck.Header.PayeeAddr = headerEntity.Address[0];
            newCheck.Header.ToBePrinted = _qboSettings.ToBePrinted;

            //ItemService ItemServ = new ItemService();
            //List<Item> findItems = ItemServ.FindAll(Initializer.sessionContext, Initializer.realmId);

            CheckLine checkedLine = new CheckLine();
            checkedLine.Amount = total;
            checkedLine.AmountSpecified = true;
            checkedLine.Desc = "Merchant Account Fees";
            decimal qty = 1;
            checkedLine.ItemsElementName = new ItemsChoiceType1[] { ItemsChoiceType1.ItemId, ItemsChoiceType1.Qty};
            checkedLine.Items = new object[] { new IdType() { idDomain = idDomainEnum.QBO, Value = GetAccountId("Merchant Account Fees")}, qty };
            newCheck.Line = new CheckLine[] { checkedLine };
            try
            {
                Check actualCheck = dataServices.Add<Check>(newCheck);
                ErrorMessageDataSource.Insert(new ErrorMessage(MessageSeverity.Info, "QBO", "Check # " + actualCheck.Header.DocNumber + " synced successfully!"));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorMessageDataSource.Insert(new ErrorMessage(MessageSeverity.Error, "QBO", ex.ToString()));
            }


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you're providing a bit of invalid data. Just like in the QuickBooks GUI, each line item on a check requires either an ACCOUNT reference, OR an ITEM reference. Hence, the error:

> You must select a product/service or an account for each split line
>   with either an amount or a billable $$customer$$.

It looks like you're trying to specify a reference to an ITEM:

```
checkedLine.ItemsElementName = new ItemsChoiceType1[] { ItemsChoiceType1.ItemId, ItemsChoiceType1.Qty};
checkedLine.Items = ...
```

But then it looks like you're specifying an ACCOUNT Id value:

```
new object[] { new IdType() { idDomain = idDomainEnum.QBO, Value = GetAccountId("Merchant Account Fees")}, qty };
```

Are you trying to specify a reference to an ITEM, or to an ACCOUNT?

Did you check the XML that this ends up generating? What does it look like? Does it conform to what is shown in the [documentation](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0400_QuickBooks_Online/Check)?

Comment: Yes, I specified an item instead of an account.